# Trying to fit a complicated bash string into a mqtt message

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, scripting, mqtt

I am trying to fit the output of the following string (that is a simple number)

```
df -hl | grep '/dev/mapper/4tb' | awk '{;percent+=$5;} END{print percent}' | column -t
```

into the following mqtt message

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.1 -p 1883 -u user -P password -t disk_usage/4tb -m *[here sould go the output of the previous command]*
```

I have tried the following script and many many of its variants (different quotes and parentesis, etc.) but I still cannot figure it out.

```
#!/bin/sh
var1='{df -hl | grep '/dev/mapper/4tb' | awk '{;percent+=$5;} END{print percent}' | column -t}'
echo $var1

mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.65 -p 1883 -u mqtt -P mqtt_password -t GC01SRVR/disk_usage -m "{\"Content\": $var1}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "static string 1 $(cmd # this is replaced by the stdout output of cmd) string 2"

echo "abc $(date --rfc-3339=seconds) xyz"
abc 2021-11-19 20:12:18+01:00 xyz
```

So in your case either

```
echo "mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.1 -p 1883 -u user -P password -t disk_usage/4tb -m $(df -hl | grep '/dev/mapper/4tb' | awk '{;percent+=$5;} END{print percent}')"
```

or

```
cmd_output="$(df -hl | grep '/dev/mapper/4tb' | awk '{;percent+=$5;} END{print percent}')"

static_string="mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.1 -p 1883 -u user -P password -t disk_usage/4tb -m "

echo "${static_string}${cmd_output}"
```